# On the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Tags: proof-explanation

We know that if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x<y$ then exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q<y.$ Now, we consider $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}.$ 
We exetend the order relation of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ In the following way $$-\infty<x<+\infty\quad\text{for all}\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

> **Question.** Based on what I said can I say that for all $x,y\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ $x<y$ exists $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q<y$?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  You already know the statement is true for $\Bbb R$ so you just need to check it for $x$ or $y = \pm \infty$.

Comment: You just need to do the cases where $x = -\infty$ or $y=+\infty$. All are pretty easy.

Comment: @RobertShore  thanks for your help. Could you show me how to work for example in the case $x=-\infty$ and $y=\infty$?

Comment: In that case literally any rational number will work.